# Problems inserting datetime data into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert data into this table, but it doesn't work, and I was changing the format to DDMMYY, DD/MM/YY, YYYY-MM-DD... and nothing change the error.

Code:

```
GO
create table PeriodoAcademico(
    CodPeriodoAcad varchar(50) not null primary key,
    Descripcion varchar(50) not null,
    FechaInicio datetime not null,
    FechaFin datetime not null,
    FechaInicioClases datetime not null,
    FechaFinClases datetime not null,
    FechaLimitePago datetime not null,
    FechaLimitePrematricula datetime not null,
    FechaLimiteRetiro datetime not null,
    FechaLimitePublicacion datetime not null
);
GO
begin tran
insert into PeriodoAcademico
values
('2019-2020-2', 'Enero-Abril 2020', '2020-01-04 06:00:00 AM', '2020-04-12 11:59:99 PM', '2020-01-08 06:00:00 AM', '2020-04-08 11:59:99 PM',
'2020-04-08 11:59:99 PM', '2020-03-08 11:59:99 PM', '2020-03-21 11:59:99 PM', '2020-04-10 11:59:99 PM');
commit
GO
```

Error:

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 77
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Completion time: 2020-03-30T17:01:44.3689635-04:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 60 seconds in a minute.

So this '2020-04-08 11:59:99 PM' is invalid.  This '2020-04-08 11:59:59 PM' is fine.  eg

```
select cast('2020-03-08 11:59:59 PM' as datetime)
```

outputs

```
2020-03-08 23:59:59.000
```

Comment: and if you want to go to the last tick then... cast('2020-03-08 11:59:59.999 PM' as datetime)